# AFNetworking SPARQL query fails with Bad URL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, sparql

I have following iOS code that uses AFNetworking to get list of Mountains. I get "Bad URL" error in my failure block.

```
 - (void) loadMountains
{
    NSString * loadMountainQueries = @"select * where { ?Mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract. FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN")) } ";        
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=%@",loadMountainQueries];

    NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [AFHTTPRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:
     [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"sparql-results+json", @"text/json", @"text/html", @"text/xml", nil]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response %@", [operation responseString]);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response %@", [operation responseString]);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

I assume `AFHTTPRequestOperation` encodes a URL automatically, but just to be sure - when I use encoded URL it gives the same response "Bad URL". Same query that works in Safari fails to work in objective C.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have a syntax error in the first line:

```
NSString * loadMountainQueries = @"select * where { ?Mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract. FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN")) } ";
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You should escape your quotation mark using the backslash:

```
... ang(?abstract),\"EN\")) } ";
```

And now the answer: You have to **percent-encode** your `loadMountainQueries` before you attach them to the main URL string:

```
NSString *loadMountainQueries = @"select * where { ?Mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract. FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),\"EN\")) } ";
NSString *encodedLoadMountainQueries = [loadMountainQueries stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=%@",encodedLoadMountainQueries];
```

The URL is valid in Safari, because it percent-encodes your URL automatically.

Comment: I already had \ for " in my code. Percent encoding worked like a charm. An additional thing I had to do was modify addAcceptableContentTypes line. I set it to: [AFHTTPRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:
     [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/sparql-results+xml", @"application/xml", nil]];

Comment: Yes, setting acceptable `ContentType`s is always a good thing. Glad I could help. :)